# Can all equalities be proven by replacing the variable with a constant?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Just out of curiosity. Given any two expressions that use a variable $x$, can replacing the $x$ with, say, an $11$ and evaluating both expressions ***always*** prove that they're equal if the results for both are the same?

If no, how? If yes, can this be used when I need to formally prove if two expressions are equal despite it looking really silly?

Comment: Take expressions $x+3x^2$ and $\sin x$. They are equal at $0$, but certainly not identically equal. But to a limited degree you can. Let $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ be polynomials of degree $n$. If they are equal at $n+1$ places, they are identically equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, take the expressions $x$ and $-x$. Replace $x=0$ and they're both the same. The expressions are different, though. To make sure the expressions are the same, you have to be able to show that *no matter what value you substitute,* the result is always the same.